# Linting file with multiple versions of Javascript / different environments

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, ecmascript-6, eslint

My protractor tests have multiple versions of Javascript in the same file. The bulk of the tests, that run in node, are ES6. Say, for example:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   ...
});
```

And then, in the same file, locators and functions passed to browser.executeScript that (by my understanding) are run in the browser (using whatever version the browser supports).

```
browser.executeScript(function() {
  window.localStorage.clear();
});
```

Is there a way I can configure eslint (or structure my tests) to lint the function passed to executeScript using different rules to the rest of the file? For example, from my testing,

```
browser.executeScript(function() {
  /* eslint-env browser */
  window.localStorage.clear();
});
```

seems to make eslint add the browser globals to the entire file, not just in the function it's declared.

Comment: According to this thread https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/2614 there doesn't seem to be a plan to allow for changing env for part of a file, only for an entire file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you could structure your project to put helper functions in one place that could be linted with one set of rules, and put your tests in another place that would be linted with a different set of rules. You can require the helper functions from the test file:

```
//helperScripts.js
module.exports = {
    clearLocalStorage: function() { window.localStorage.clear(); }
}

//testFile.js
var helperScripts = require('../otherFolder/helperScripts.js');
browser.executeScript(helperScripts.clearLocalStorage);
```